# Get Event from v-file-input on change in Vuetify

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuetify.js, laravel-7

I am using Laravel With vue.js along Vuetify. I'm working on the registration form. I'm passing the image file. for that I'm checking console for getting the image in `(event)` but it not working. it showing image value in `File` in console I what to get image value in `event`

**like this I am calling console thing**

```
  methods: {
   onFileSelected(event){
     console.log(event);
   },
```

**console result coming like this**

```
File {name: "Webp.net-resizeimage.jpg", lastModified: 1603892951080, lastModifiedDate: Wed Oct 28 2020 19:19:11 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time), webkitRelativePath: "", size: 27077, …}
lastModified: 1603892951080
lastModifiedDate: Wed Oct 28 2020 19:19:11 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time) {}
name: "Webp.net-resizeimage.jpg"
size: 27077
type: "image/jpeg"
webkitRelativePath: ""
__proto__: File
```

my registration form

```
<template>
  <div>
    <v-row justify="center">
      <v-col cols="12" sm="6">
        <form enctype="multipart/form-data">
          <v-card ref="form">
            <v-card-text>
              <h2 class="text-center">Business Register</h2>
              <v-divider class="mt-3"></v-divider>

              <v-col cols="12" sm="12">
                <v-text-field
                  v-model.trim="form.owner_name"
                  type="text"
                  label="Owner Name"
                  outlined
                  autocomplete="off"
                ></v-text-field>
              </v-col>

              <v-col cols="12" sm="12">
                <v-file-input
                  label="shop_front_image"
                  outlined
                  autocomplete="off"
                  @change="onFileSelected"
                ></v-file-input>
              </v-col>

              <v-card-actions>
                <v-btn
                  rounded
                  type="submit"
                  :loading="loading"
                  color="primary"
                  dark
                  >Register</v-btn
                >
              </v-card-actions>
              <br />
            </v-card-text>
          </v-card>
        </form>
      </v-col>
    </v-row>
  </div>
</template>

<script >
export default {
  created() {
    if (!User.loggedIn()) {
      this.$router.push({ name: "Login" });
    }
  },
  data() {
    return {
      loading: false,

      form: {
        owner_name: "",

        shop_front_image: "",
      },
      errors: {},
    };
  },
  methods: {
    onFileSelected(event) {
      console.log(event);
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: Did you tried with: `event.target.files[0]`?

Comment: @mare96 yes i did That i fined problem in image input flied for i tryid 
                  <input
                    type="file"
                    id="customFile"
                    @change="onFileSelected"
                  /> know it working but its an bootstrap how can i fix in my vuetify

Comment: @mare96 tried event.target.file[0]  but it giving TypeError: Cannot read property 'files' of undefined error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can read in the [documentation](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-file-input/#events) about Events for the input field in vuetify.

When you trigger `@change` you will get `File[]` not `Event`.

You can pass `$event` as second parameter like:

```
@change="onFileSelected('something', $event)"
```

Taken from [here](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/10725).

Also, you can try to pass `$event` with `@input` like this:

```
@input="onFileSelected($event)"
```

Not tested but I hope something of that will help you.